# enable a disabled button by exiting off a form inside a form

Tags: c#, winforms

OK This is what I am doing.

StartMenu form has button2- When button 2 is clicked it brings up a new form and gets disabled. 
Now new form (InchMm conversion form) is up and when I am done with that form I hit the X button. When this is done I want Button2 from StartMenu form to enable. My code below.

StartMenu

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        InchMm_Conversion f = new InchMm_Conversion();
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
    }

    public void enableB() 
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

InchMm Conversion form

```
private void InchMm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
    {
        StartMenu.enableB();

    }
```

Now I am getting a error that says a object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property. Now I know this should be its right in form of my face but I am still learning alot and I think I am close.

Comment: Why not use modal form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        InchMm_Conversion f = new InchMm_Conversion();
        f.MdiParent = this;
//Here you set an event. When the form closes the here specified method is called 
        f.FormClosed += f_FormClosed; 
        f.Show();
        button2.Enabled = false;
}


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
}       

//This method is executed when the form is closed
    void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
           button2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Even though this should work, you should think about using a modal form as Reniuz said ;)

Comment: What I am doing is allowing more then one from to open from the startmenu form like form1 and form2 beside the main form. What I want to stop is InchMm form from being open more then once.

Comment: Okay, than what you are doing is correct i suppose :). Has my answer worked for you or is there anything i can clarify ?

Comment: Yes I am sorry I don't understand where that goes in my code. Could you link some place that may explain what you did?

Comment: i changed my example so that it is more clear what happens and where it has to go. For further information i would suggest that you read about events in C#

Comment: Ok thats clear and I thank you! I am going to read up more on events as well. This makes more since then trying to do this from different forms!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `InchMm_Conversion()` constructor to `InchMm_Conversion(StartMenuForm)`. So you can pass the 'parent' dialog to InchMm_Conversion in construction. Hold a reference in a private field and you can access it when you close the child form. (`ReferenceToStartMenuForm.enableB()`) (I know there are more elegant solutions, but this is quite easy to implement)

```
InchMm_Conversion(StartMenuForm form)
{
    myForm = form;    
}

private void InchMm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    myForm.enableB();

}
private StartMenuForm myForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside other answers, which are correct, I want to suggest other solution. Because you using `IsMdiContainer` and `MDIParent` (by the way its strange that you setting MDI Container on button click) in your child form you can access parent form like this:

```
private void InchMm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    StartMenu form = this.MDIParent as StartMenu;
    if(form != null)
       form.enableB();
}
```

Comment: i like that one, its nice an simple . +1